# Can Only Access Results for one of my surveys

Tags: response, surveymonkey

I've created a web application that using SurveyMonkey API and gathers the responses to a bunch of surveys I've created with SurveyMonkey. It's a BASIC account, however when I call the method get_responses on a survey it only works for one of my surveys.

I have 6 surveys that have been completed but it returns a json response with null values for 5 of my surveys.

"{"status": 0, "data": [null, null, null, null, null, null]}"

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call get_respondent_list for each individual survey, and then pass a list of respondent ids to get_responses in the parameter 'respondent_ids'.  You also need to ensure you pass the correct survey_id to get_responses.  If you're getting null values, this means you are either passing invalid respondent ids, or respondent ids that do not correspond to the survey_id you are sending.

See here for more info: https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_responses and https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_respondent_list

Comment: Thanks that helped me find where my bug was :-)